# Python Web Scrapping Error 403 even with header User Agent

Tags: python, web-scraping, url, user-agent, http-status-code-403

I'm a newbie learning Python. While using BeautifulSoup and Requests to scrap  "https://batdongsan.com.vn/nha-dat-ban-tp-hcm"  for collect data on housing price of my hometown, I get blocked by 403 error even though having tried Headers User Agent. Here is my code :

**url3 = "https://batdongsan.com.vn/nha-dat-ban-tp-hcm"

headers = {"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.5060.114 Safari/537.36 Edg/103.0.1264.49"}

page = requests.get(url3, headers = headers)

print(page)**

**Result : <Response [403]>**

Have anyone tried and succeeded to bypass the same problem. Any help is highly appriciated.

Many thanks

Comment: 403 means unauthorized, does this app require any authentification ?

Comment: I think the site detects that I try to scrap ils contenu then blocks me. But the code of platipus on fire below can help bypass the system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import cloudscraper

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()

soup = BeautifulSoup(scraper.get("https://batdongsan.com.vn/nha-dat-ban-tp-hcm").text)

print(soup.text) ## do what you want with the response
```

You can install cloudscraper with `pip install cloudscraper`

Comment: Thank you agent P :)) . I try your soulution tonight and keep you informed.

Comment: update : It works, thank you a lot, you just save me hours of googling.